# Lost character/s during encrypt-decrypt using rijindeal algorthm in c#

Tags: c#

I have implement code Encrypt and Decrypt method. Input string value  passed  to encrypt method and get the encrypt value stored in xml file . after I getting encrypted value to read xml file using Decrypt Method to read value. I am getting Error in rare case(Encrypted input value is not correct and Decrypted output value). how do i resolve this Issue . Please share to me .
Here Sample code

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    try
    {                   


        string incoming = cipherText.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
        switch (cipherText.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: incoming += "=="; break;
            case 3: incoming += "="; break;
        }
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(incoming);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                  

          return "Exception";
    }
}
```

Comment: change Ascii Encoding to UTF8 encoding.  Ascii encoding with removve non-printable characters.  I suspect that occasionally the encryption is generating characters that the Ascii encoding is removing.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding manually a padding to the end of the data, if you don't reverse that on the decipher then it would not work (it must be added after decripting as you did it before).

But, also, that padding is unnecessary, AES256 needs the data to be padded, yes, but the cryptostream will do that for you, so if you remove all that padding stuff it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**USE Trim() Function AND REMOVE ALL OF THE WHITE SPACES**

This issue may occur when there are white spaces.
Use Trim() function to remove white spaces.

**example -:  cipherText.Trim()**